# Lucidworks Custom connector get last job time

Tags: java, oracle, lucidworks

Need to get last successful job runtime in custom java connector.

[image]

Is it possible to get Last run start value, or any other way to store and retrieve last job run time?

Tried to get last job time by accessing history api service. 
`curl -u user:pass fusion-host:6764/api/jobs/datasource:movies-db/history`

Is there any other way to get values from connector itself?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read any documentation from Lucidworks on the topic?

Comment: Yes i tried to get last job time by accessing history api service. curl -u user:pass http://fusion-host:6764/api/jobs/datasource:movies-db/history

Answer (score -1):

https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion-server/4.0/reference/api/jobs-api.html#get-the-job-history-for-a-datasource

Based on these docs, the response should be similar to this. You would use startTime for last run start

```
[ {
  "resource" : "datasource:movies-db",
  "startTime" : "2017-05-17T21:01:46.743Z",
  "endTime" : "2017-05-17T21:02:05.720Z",
  "status" : "success"
}, {
  "resource" : "datasource:movies-db",
  "startTime" : "2017-05-17T20:58:10.503Z",
  "endTime" : "2017-05-17T20:58:42.020Z",
  "status" : "success"
} ]
```

Comment: I already retrieved value from Rest api. I am exploring is there any other way to retrieve values from connector.